# A generic noun for something being compared?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm looking for a noun to use in place of "comparable object," which would make sense in the following context:

> Four "comparable objects" were ranked based on their performance in a recent comparison.

I keep thinking of the word "competitor," but I'm not satisfied with it, which made me think of the following analogy:

```
competitor : competition :: ??? : comparison
```

Comment: I bet you need it for a java program.

Comment: lol, Python actually :)

Comment: In English, I can't think of one.  In programming-speak, "comparand", by analogy with "operand". :-)

Comment: Comparable is an acceptable English word but it does imply that they are roughly equivalent - eg "the Mercedes and BMW have comparable running costs".

Comment: @Martin +1 for *comparable*.  In many computer languages the name of the interface to implement when you need to develop a *compareTo* method is named precisely *comparable* - for instance *class stuff implements comparable*. Therefore each of the compared object is a "Comparable".  That's the correct answer IMO.

Comment: Comparable is an adjective; has it become a noun too?

Comment: @monica in a technical sense yes, just as countable is a noun in maths.

Comment: @Alain - just pointing out that 'comparable' has extra meanings in English beyond it's software/maths usage

Comment: @Monica in this occurrence, it is just a shorter way of meaning *comparable object*.  You will probably agree with le that in OOP, objects can be compared only if they have a common object type (principal or inherited) which implements the Comparable interface.   A class name or in that case an interface name *is* a noun.

Comment: I don't see how "comparable" and "countable" are suddenly nouns, in any context. They both **describe** *that which can be compared/counted*. In programming (Java), *implementing Comparable* is simply **describing** that an object is one which can be compared to others.

Comment: @Alain, sure, in programming contexts, I talk about comparables and countables and other -ables all the time as nouns, because that's the convention in that context.  I'm not sure if I would do it in a general context yet.  Though adjectives do lose their nouns over time -- e.g. laptop, cell -- so this is probably a matter of timing, not absolute yes/no.

Comment: @Monica: 'comparable' may be use as a 'substantive'  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantive#Substantive_as_a_word_for_noun (itself a substantive adjective, used as a noun) (cf. 'the good, the bad, and the ugly')

Comment: @Monica Cellio, why not propose comparand as an answer? I like it.

Comment: @JeffSahol: done (via edit, since I already had an answer -- hope that's the right process).

Comment: @Dolph the nearest I can find is "comparate" ;)

Comment: Thanks for the bounty, RiMMER! I came here to accept an answer but I'll give it another 48 hours or so :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One possible word is [comparate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Comparate), defined as follows:

> Com"pa*rate\, n. [L. comparatum, fr.
>   comparatus, p. p. of comparare. See
>   1st Compare.] (Logic) One of two
>   things compared together.

Comment: Say a foreigner doesn't know what an orange is and you compare it with an apple. Both fruits are comparates, but only the apple is the "compared object", is that correct?

Answer (score 10):

- alternatives
- candidates
- contenders
- considerations

Four alternatives were ranked based on their appropriateness in the above sentence :)

Comment: My issue with "alternatives" and "candidates" is that they imply that one object is "correct" and all the rest are "wrong." "Considerations" are *how*, or perhaps *why*, you judge something, not so much the entities of your comparison.

Upvote for **contenders**, although colloquially, I struggle to apply it to inanimate objects.

Comment: +1 for contenders. If it were me though I'd just say: "Four *things* were ranked based on their performance in a recent comparison."

Comment: Or "Four items (...)". Something like "analogous items/entities" also came to my mind. Knowing a little more of the nature of the entity being compared could help.

Answer (score 7):

I'm pretty confident the word you're looking for is *comparee*. A *comparee* should be "that which is being compared", just as an *employee* is "that who is being employed".

It goes on to a *comparer*: that which compares, just as an *employer*: that who employs.

If anyone speaks latin here, maybe they could also share a latin word for this?

Answer (score 6):

Options?

Representative (members) (of the class)?  e.g. Consumer Reports looked at these four representative small cars.

Candidates?  I know you don't like the implication that there is one best candidate, so this depends on context -- that applies to elections more than to which restaurant you're going to dine at tonight.

From the discussion in comments, "comparables" would work if it's not too geeky for your context.  I would personally hesitate to use it in general discourse.

Edited to add: also from the comments, "comparand" by analogy with "operand", if your audience would grok that.

Comment: I'm voting this up for *comparand* (which is what immediately came to my mind when I saw the question).  There is plenty of [programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality.aspx) [precedent](http://www.google.com/patents/about?id=Bch_AAAAEBAJ).  Also, besides *operand*, one might look to *dividend* as a model (and reject *comparator*, which is closest to *divisor*).  I don't really have much defense against *comparate*, with @pageman's killer citation, beyond "It just doesn't sound/look/feel as good as *comparand*".

Answer (score 2):

***Options*** seems to be the most flexible and functional, and works in the sentence.

It's mildly awkward, however. I suspect the actual noun -- printers, trucks, lighthouses, coffeemakers -- is usually used in such a sentence for that very reason.

Comment: *Options* doesn't imply a comparison. Options are things you choose between.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for *comparator*, and it may be why your brain keeps giving you *competitor*, because they sound somewhat similar.

From NOAD:

> **comparator** |kəmˈparətər|
>   *noun*
>   a device for comparing a measurable property or thing with a reference or standard.
>   • an electronic circuit for comparing two electrical signals.
>   • something used as a standard for comparison.

Comment: The comparator performs the comparison; it isn't a thing being compared.

Comment: @Monica Cellio That's not quite right. The comparator is the standard that others are compared to, but it doesn't actually perform the comparison.

Comment: @Kit, it does mean that the answer doesn't answer the qeustion.

Comment: @Kit: in a programming context a comparator usually does perform the comparison (between two values, one of which may be "this" in OOP).  In what contexts is the comparator the yardstick?

Comment: In Portal 2, there is a device that accepts or discards sentry units by comparing them with a known correct sentry. By the first definition, the *device* is the comparator. By the third, the *reference sentry* is the comparator. By none of the three definitions can the sentry *being checked* be the comparator.