# Is there a linguistic term that denotes 'levels of comparison' of words?

Tags: single-word-requests

The class of words called 'words of comparison' includes words such as 'higher' and 'highest'. The words 'higher' and 'highest' express comparative height. The term for the class of words that includes 'higher' is 'the comparative'. The term for the class of words that includes 'highest' is 'the superlative'.

Is there a linguistic term that denotes the class of properties that words of comparison compare?

I'd appreciate whatever answers people can offer, but I'd prefer answers that include a completion one of these two similes.

- The word 'higher' and the word 'highest' are to the word 'height' as the phrase 'the comparative' and the phrase 'the superlative' are to '_____'.
- The word 'higher' and the word 'highest' are to the property called 'height' as the phrase 'the comparative' and the phrase 'the superlative' are to _____.

Thank you,

-Hal

Comment: Note: The question *A generic noun for something being compared?* (http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27047/a-generic-noun-for-something-being-compared) does not ask the same question that I've asked.

Comment: I'd just call them _qualities_ or _attributes_. Or _measures_ to refer just to qualities that are measurable and comparable.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the reply. I'm writing a philosophy paper about properties. I've tried a few versions of phrases like "qualities that are comparable". They all had problems. 'Qualities' doesn't distinguish between qualities in general and 'comparable qualities'. 'Comparable qualities' doesn't express that the comparison is a comparison of the degree of exhibition of a quality. Phrases like 'comparison of the degree of exhibition of a quality' are abstruse. Hence, my predicament.

Comment: They're not really related directly. _Higher_ and _highest_ are related by [inflection (not derivation)](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf) to the positive degree adjective _high_, which is the root. _High_, an adjective, is also related to _height_, a noun, by abstract nominalization, which is derivation (not inflection). So there is no neat proportion, alas. You hafta look at the details.

Comment: @JohnLawler You mean to say that the relation is conceptual, and not linguistic, and so there is no linguistic term for what I've described? (The derivation/inflection distinction is a useful one. I wasn't aware of it. Thank you.)

Comment: And if you're writing a philosophy paper, I highly recommend Frawley's _Linguistic Semantics_ (Erlbaum 1992). Here's a [question list](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/meta4/frawleyq.pdf) and [a chapter outline for Entities (aka "nouns")](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/meta4/FrawleyEntities.pdf) from my old lexical semantics class.

Comment: @Hal: I'm not sure I'd put it that way; I think you're starting with the idea that there are lexical parallels for everything, which is not true. Some lexical items like _left/right, up/down, mother/father/child_ come in sets, prepackaged with presuppositions and cultural values, but others are only distantly related, and may well have no central "root", only a prototype that's pretty abstract.

Comment: Are you really looking for a _linguistic_ term rather than the word for the _concept_ of things that can be compared on a continuum?

Comment: To @Barmar's point, I'm not immersed enough in linguistics to suggest a grammatical term, but in general usage, we'd call *height* & friends a *metric* (or *dimension*).

Answer (score 4):

Attributes that can be placed on a [cline](http://dictionary.infoplease.com/cline) (linguistics: *a scale of continuous gradation; continuum*) can be "quantified" using [gradable adjectives](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-reference/adjectives-gradable-non-gradable) *(cold, colder, coldest, very cold, a bit cold, too cold)*.

Correspondingly, those attributes that *aren't* normally quantified in this way are identified using "non-gradable" adjectives *(married, freezing, dead)*. I therefore think it's quite reasonable to call these ***non-gradable attributes***.